# Run python code on Databricks, using multiprocessing

Tags: python, pyspark, cassandra, multiprocessing, azure-databricks

I have the following code that is my final attemp to port some operation done in sequential order to parallel executions. This is code that I run on Databricks and I wanted to speed up the execution.

The approach is simple (in theory): split the input dataframe in 4, for each part read every line and execute some function for writing on cassandra. While use the code in sequential order, this works just fine except for computational time. I cannot figure out what is wrong with this multiprocess approach.

```
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time
import pyodbc
import pandas
import multiprocessing
import os


def info(title):
    print(title)
    print('module name:', __name__)
    print('parent process:', os.getppid())
    print('process id:', os.getpid())


def get_hc_info_from_active_campaign() -> DataFrame:


    query = '''(
            select hc.id  HeadcounterId
        ,hc.Name as HeadcounterName
        ,hc.[DeviceId]
        ,c.[id] as CampaignId
        ,c.[startDate]
        ,c.[stopDate]
                FROM  [dbo].[MD_Headcounters] hc
                join MD_Campaigns as C
                on hc.CampaignId=C.Id
                where c.StopDate >CONVERT(date,GETDATE()-1)) as hc_info_from_active_campaign
            '''

    hc_info_from_active_campaign = (spark.read
                                                .format("jdbc")
                                                .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://{0}:{1};database={2}".format(jdbcHostname_prod, jdbcPort, jdbcDatabase_prod))
                                                .option("dbtable", query)
                                                .option("user", sql_user_prod)
                                                .option("password", sql_password_prod)
                                                .load()
                                                )
    
    return hc_info_from_active_campaign

def compute_new_base_values(timestamp_inf: str, timestamo_sup: str, device_id: str, category: str):
    cassandra_h_aggr_df = read_from_cassandra_prod('headcounter_category_h_aggr').where((F.col('device_id')== device_id) & (F.col('timestamp') <= timestamo_sup) & (F.col('timestamp') >= timestamp_inf) & (F.col('category')==category)).fillna(0)
    
    cassandra_h_aggr_consolidated_hystory_df = (cassandra_h_aggr_df
                                        .withColumn('delta_ots', F.greatest(F.col('estimated_ots'), F.col('ots')) - F.least(F.col('estimated_ots'), F.col('ots')))
                                        .withColumn('delta_views', F.greatest(F.col('estimated_views'), F.col('views')) - F.least(F.col('estimated_views'), F.col('views')))
                                        .withColumn('delta_attentiont_milliseconds', F.greatest(F.col('estimated_attentiont_milliseconds'), F.col('attentiont_milliseconds')) - F.least(F.col('estimated_attentiont_milliseconds'), F.col('attentiont_milliseconds')))
                                        .withColumn('delta_dwell_milliseconds', F.greatest(F.col('estimated_dwell_milliseconds'), F.col('dwell_milliseconds')) - F.least(F.col('estimated_dwell_milliseconds'), F.col('dwell_milliseconds')))
                                        .withColumn('min_ots', F.least(F.col('estimated_ots'), F.col('ots')))
                                        .withColumn('min_views', F.least(F.col('estimated_views'), F.col('views')))
                                        .withColumn('min_attentiont_milliseconds', F.least(F.col('estimated_attentiont_milliseconds'), F.col('attentiont_milliseconds')))
                                        .withColumn('min_dwell_milliseconds', F.least(F.col('estimated_dwell_milliseconds'), F.col('dwell_milliseconds')))
                                        )

    consolidated_hystory_df = (cassandra_h_aggr_consolidated_hystory_df
                        .withColumn('base_ots', F.col('delta_ots')+F.col('min_ots'))
                        .withColumn('base_views', F.col('delta_views')+F.col('min_views'))
                        .withColumn('base_attentiont_milliseconds', F.col('delta_attentiont_milliseconds')+F.col('min_attentiont_milliseconds'))
                        .withColumn('base_dwell_milliseconds', F.col('delta_dwell_milliseconds')+F.col('min_dwell_milliseconds'))
                        )

    consolidated_hystory_df = (consolidated_hystory_df
                        .groupBy('device_id', 'category')
                        .agg(
                            F.sum('estimated_ots').alias('sum_estimated_ots'),
                            F.sum('base_ots').alias('sum_base_ots'),
                            F.sum('ots').alias('sum_ots'),
                            F.sum('estimated_views').alias('sum_estimated_views'),
                            F.sum('base_views').alias('sum_base_views'),
                            F.sum('views').alias('sum_views'),
                            F.sum('estimated_attentiont_milliseconds').alias('sum_estimated_attentiont_milliseconds'),
                            F.sum('base_attentiont_milliseconds').alias('sum_base_attentiont_milliseconds'),
                            F.sum('attentiont_milliseconds').alias('sum_attentiont_milliseconds'),
                            F.sum('estimated_dwell_milliseconds').alias('sum_estimated_dwell_milliseconds'),
                            F.sum('base_dwell_milliseconds').alias('sum_base_dwell_milliseconds'),
                            F.sum('dwell_milliseconds').alias('sum_dwell_milliseconds')
                        )
                        )


    updated_base_values_df =(consolidated_hystory_df
                                                    .withColumn('BaseOts', F.col('sum_base_ots')-F.col('sum_ots'))
                                                    .withColumn('BaseViews', F.col('sum_base_views')-F.col('sum_views'))
                                                    .withColumn('BaseDwellTimeMilliseconds', F.col('sum_base_dwell_milliseconds')-F.col('sum_dwell_milliseconds'))
                                                    .withColumn('BaseAttentionTimeMilliseconds', F.col('sum_base_attentiont_milliseconds')-F.col('sum_attentiont_milliseconds'))
                                            )                                                       
    
    updated_base_values_df = updated_base_values_df.select('BaseOts','BaseViews','BaseDwellTimeMilliseconds','BaseAttentionTimeMilliseconds').rdd.map(lambda row: row.asDict()).collect()[0]
    return updated_base_values_df

def get_cassandra_sum(campaign_id: str, headcounter_id: str, category: str):
    df = read_from_cassandra_dev('temp_sum_headcounter_category').where((F.col('campaign_id')==campaign_id) & (F.col('headcounter_id')==headcounter_id) & (F.col('category')==category))
    return df

def update_campaing_headcounter_sum(headcounter_campaign_list: list, start: int, end: int, queue: multiprocessing.Queue):

    yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(days = 1)
    yesterday = yesterday.date()
    

    for elem in headcounter_campaign_list[start:end]:
        timestamp_inf = elem['startDate'].strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00")
        timestamo_sup = yesterday.strftime("%Y-%m-%d 23:00:00")
        device_id = elem['DeviceId']
        headcounter_id = elem['HeadcounterId']
        campaign_id = elem['CampaignId']
        for category in ['PERSON','VEHICLE']:
            new_base_values = compute_new_base_values(timestamp_inf, timestamo_sup, device_id, category)
            temp_sum_headcounter_category_df = get_cassandra_sum(campaign_id, headcounter_id, category)
            new_temp_headcounter_category_df = (temp_sum_headcounter_category_df
                                            .withColumn('base_ots',new_base_values['BaseOts']- F.col('base_ots'))
                                            .withColumn('base_views',new_base_values['BaseViews']- F.col('base_views'))
                                            .withColumn('base_dwell_milliseconds',new_base_values['BaseDwellTimeMilliseconds']- F.col('base_dwell_milliseconds'))
                                            .withColumn('base_attention_milliseconds',new_base_values['BaseAttentionTimeMilliseconds'] - F.col('base_attention_milliseconds'))
                                            ).select('campaign_id','headcounter_id','category','base_ots', 'base_views','base_dwell_milliseconds','base_attention_milliseconds')
            queue.put(f'{start} - {end}')
            write_on_cassandra_dev(new_temp_headcounter_category_df, 'temp_sum_headcounter_category')

    def consolidate_base(hc_info_from_active_campaign_list):    

        num_processes = os.cpu_count()
        # Calcola le dimensioni delle sotto-liste per ciascun processo
        chunk_size = len(hc_info_from_active_campaign_list) // num_processes
        processes = []
        queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

        for i in range(num_processes):
            start = i * chunk_size
            end = (i + 1) * chunk_size if i < num_processes - 1 else len(hc_info_from_active_campaign_list)
            process = multiprocessing.Process(target=update_campaing_headcounter_sum, args=(hc_info_from_active_campaign_list, start, end, queue))
            processes.append(process)
            process.start()

       
        for process in processes:
            process.join()

        while not queue.empty():
            print(queue.get())


days_intervall = 1
start_script = time.time()
yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(days = days_intervall)
yesterday = yesterday.date()
hc_info_from_active_campaign_list = get_hc_info_from_active_campaign().rdd.map(lambda row: row.asDict()).collect()
print('--------')


consolidate_base(hc_info_from_active_campaign_list)
```

Thank you all for the answers.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Can you go a bit into more detail about what's wrong? Does it work? Is it just to slow compared to sequential?

Comment: Hi Raja. It's seams this does not work at all. Databricks job runs normal but tis does not write antything on cassandra. When I try to print something inside the process does not print anything, and If I try to display the dataframe before writing the job seams to go on forever